# Why i can't see desired data in jsp file

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new in Java EE and I am building a web application with maven, spring mvc
and hibernate.

I have a problem with the jsp. I can not show the data of object with the expression / jstl 
language. In console doesn't show any error. Any suggestions?

Pom.xml:

[image: Pom.xml]

Controller:

[image: Controller]

Inicio.jsp:

[image: Inicio.jsp]

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the controller you are setting the object with key

```
model.addObject("usuario", usuarioo);
```

The first character is small 'u'.

And in your jsp you are trying to access using **U**suario. Thus the value is not getting printed.

Kindly use something like

```
${usuario.nombre}
```